# Windows C++/CLI Exception "Destination array was not long enough. check destindex and length and the array's lower bounds"

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have code which is written in Windows C++/CLI. The executable can run OK for hours but equally it can randomly crash after 10 minutes. When it crashes it generates the error message "array was not long enough. check destindex and length and the array's lower bounds"

It always crashes on the same line of a function AddLogItemRange(). The AddLogItemRange function is called every 500ms and when invoked it takes as a parameter a List of ListViewItem's which are written to a Listwiew window on a GUI.

Having looked at some C# responses to a similar question on Stack Overflow, it is apparent that this is occurring because ToArray() when invoked from within the function AddLogItemRange is not thread safe. I'm not sure how to refactor this code in order to make it thread safe and I would appreciate any advice. The gist of my code is below.

```
private: static System::Collections::Generic::List<ListViewItem^>^ viewList;

private: System::Void AddLogItemRange( List<ListViewItem^>^ myList )
     {
         try
         {
             // If we need to Invoke the the update of the control then...
            if( true == this->linkFaultListBox->InvokeRequired )
            {
                // Create a delegate to this function.
                AddItemRangeCallback^ func = gcnew AddItemRangeCallback( this, &Form1::AddLogItemRange );

                // Invoke this function on the same thread as the control.
                this->Invoke( func, myList );
            }

            // else just update the control.
            else
            {
                if( nullptr == myList)
                {
                    Console::WriteLine("Null equals myList");
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    this->listView1->Items->AddRange( myList->ToArray() ); //Exception is thrown here`
```

Main body of code where Function invoked every 500ms

viewList is likely to be be getting updated 3 or 4 times every 500ms

```
         if( 0 != viewList->Count )
         {
             
             
             AddLogItemRange( viewList );
             viewList->Clear();
         }
```

viewList is updated in a single place from within the function UpdateDisplay() which gets called from multiple places within the program

```
private: System::Void UpdateDisplay( String^ param )
        {
            try
            {
                ListViewItem^ item = gcnew ListViewItem();
                item->Text = Convert::ToString( seqNo++ );
                item->SubItems->Add( param );  

                viewList->Add( item );

            }
```

Comment: Yes, a threading race bug is the likely cause.  Happens when a worker thread adds an item to the list, just as the UI thread is busy executing ToArray().  We can't see that code, so specific advice is hard to give, but safe to assume you should use Monitor to protect access to the list.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am fairly new to this so struggling to fully understand what is being suggested. I have amended the question to show how viewList is accessed. When you suggest I should use Monitor would it be possible to elaborate what is meant by this

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to change

```
this->Invoke( func, myList );
```

to

```
this->Invoke( func, myList->Clone() );
```

or just as good

```
this->Invoke( func, gcnew List<ListViewItem^>(myList) );
```

That way the UI thread gets its own separate list object, which is not being modified in the worker thread at the same time the UI is using it.

That said, this is a little wasteful, as you are just going to call `ToArray()` which itself makes a copy.  For that you could have `AddLogItemRange` accept an array handle and move `ToArray()` to the caller.